# Amazon AWS Route53 Delegate Subdomain Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, dns, amazon-route53

I've followed these [instructions 'Creating a Subdomain That Uses Amazon Route 53 as the DNS Service without Migrating the Parent Domain'](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html#CreateZoneNewSubdomain) many times over without success. I configured a domain a couple of weeks ago and let it sit, I'm revisiting today and it's still not working.

My parent domain haynesandcompany.com is hosted with arvixe.com.

Here's my steps I took to implement as per the instructions;

1. Created a hosted zone 'helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com' on Route53.
2. Created a subdomain on my host arvixe.com for 'helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com', removed the NS records and replaced them with the NS records reported by Route53.
3. At this point the DNS config on arvixe for the subdomain contains 4 NS records only, nothing else.
4. Back on Route53 I created a TXT record to validate my work with the value "bensayshello" and also created an A record pointing to my Elastic Load Balancer instance ALIAS. My config on route 53 looks like this;

   ```
   helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com A ALIAS dualstack.awseb-e-q-awsebloa-14c3yer0oht29-329340065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. Routing Policy: Simple, Evaluate Target Health: No
   helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com NS ns-1845.awsdns-38.co.uk, ns-906.awsdns-49.net, ns-1063.awsdns-04.org, ns-461.awsdns-57.com
   helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com SOA ns-1845.awsdns-38.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
   helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com TXT "bensayshello"
   www.helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com A ALIAS dualstack.awseb-e-q-awsebloa-14c3yer0oht29-329340065.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. Routing Policy: Simple, Evaluate Target Health: No
   ```

Based on my understanding, navigating to helloamazon.haynesandcompany.com now should work but it fails. dnsstuff.com DNS report serves up a bunch of warnings and errors and running a propagation test on whatsmydns.com shows every 2nd server OK, the rest return a fail. Mind you, it's been weeks since I set this all up so I don't think it's just a matter of giving it more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your mistake.

> Created a subdomain on my host ... removed the NS records

If you did this correctly, there would not be any NS records for you to "remove."  Based on that, don't create a separate subdomain as its own entity at the other DNS provider.  There's going to be nothing to tie that back to the parent domain.

Inside the *existing* parent domain, at the other DNS provider, just create records of type NS for the *host* "helloamazon" using the name servers assigned to the hosted zone in Route 53.

That should be all you need.